# Rank of an user displays correctly, but not when I try to display national rank

Tags: php, mysql, rank

My code works fine if I just display the global rank of the users in my database

```
function getUserRank($userId){
    $sql1       = "SET @rownum := 0";

    $sql2       =   "SELECT rank, level FROM (
                    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, level, id
                    FROM accounts ORDER BY level DESC
                    ) as result WHERE id=$userId";

    mysql_query($sql1);
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);
    $rows = '';
    $data = array();
    if (!empty($result))
        $rows      =  mysql_num_rows($result);
    else
        $rows      =  '';

    if (!empty($rows)){
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[]   = $rows;
        }
    }


    if (empty($data[0]['rank']))
        return 1;
    return $data[0]['rank'];  }
```

However, if I modify the 7th line   `WHERE id=$userId, country='".$statsrow['country']."'"`, then every user gets Rank 1, when It should display normal ranks for each country, like it does when its global. Did I place the country condition wrongly? I just dont understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: change your comma between the where conditions to `and` like this `WHERE id=$userId and country='".$statsrow['country']."'"`

Comment: May be you are missing AND between two conditions. WHERE id=$userId AND country='".$statsrow['country']."'"

Comment: Damn, sometimes you just don't realise the smallest mistakes. Thanks guys, I'm gonna blame it on the fact I didn't sleep too much.

Comment: It still doesn't work though. Everybody still has Rank 1, no matter what. I dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the column `country` in the subquery select clause, see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f9d6/1) as an example. Also note the cross join I show below helps you avoid needing 2 sql statements.

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
    (`id` int, `level` int, `country` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO accounts
    (`id`, `level`, `country`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a'),
    (1, 2, 'a'),
    (3, 1, 'a'),
    (4, 3, 'a'),
    (1, 4, 'a'),
    (6, 1, 'a'),
    (7, 5, 'a')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT rank, level 
FROM (
      SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, level, id, country
      FROM accounts
      CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0 x) var
      ORDER BY level DESC
      ) as result 
WHERE id=1
and country = 'a'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f9d6/1/0)**:

```
| rank | level |
|------|-------|
|    4 |     2 |
|    5 |     1 |
|    2 |     4 |
```